# Vuforia Android Studio No DRP key due to exception

Tags: vuforia

I am trying to make an android app with using Vuforia liblary.

But I face with

```
No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
```

I did not find any solution exactly about vuforia.

Do you can help me to handle it?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explicitly clear.

There are no class found at this package : com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

Your integration may be wrong. Follow the instructions from Vuforia developer [page](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-Android-Development) and make sure you've implemented everything correctly.